# No subject alternative DNS name matching

Tags: java, post, https

I am trying to perform POST request in Java. I have succeded with HTTP, but HTTPS is tricky for me.
I am using this code:

```
// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
        new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
            public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
            public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }
};

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
} catch (Exception e) {
}


String httpsURL = "https://requestb.in/191g0961";

String query = "email="+URLEncoder.encode("abc@xyz.com","UTF-8"); 
query += "&";
query += "password="+URLEncoder.encode("abcd","UTF-8") ;

URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");

con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length())); 
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0;Windows98;DigExt)"); 
con.setDoOutput(true); 
con.setDoInput(true); 

DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());  

output.writeBytes(query);

output.close();

DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream()); 


for( int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read() ) 
    System.out.print( (char)c ); 
input.close(); 

System.out.println("Resp Code:"+con .getResponseCode()); 
System.out.println("Resp Message:"+ con .getResponseMessage());
```

I have added TrustManager in hope it solves my problem, because when I load my testing webpage https://requestb.in/191g0961 in Firefox, it says that site uses untrusted certificate, etc..

My code works with pages that are loaded in Firefox without any warnings, like this page: https://extranet.nix.cz/login (you can try it)

But with https://requestb.in/191g0961 it is giving me following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching requestb.in found.
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at https.Sender.main(Sender.java:80)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching requestb.in found.
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
```

Have you any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

**Solution:**

I have created this simple class:

```
public class Verifier implements HostnameVerifier {

    public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return true;   // mark everything as verified
    }
}
```

and then I added:

```
con.setHostnameVerifier(new Verifier());
```

Comment: Have you checked that your methods from the `TrustManager` are called? Especially the method `checkServerTrusted()` is needed.

Comment: I just tried it and method `checkServerTrusted()` is really called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You also have to set a `HostnameVerifier` in the `HttpsURLConnection`. This has to verify that the hostname is accepted by your implementation.

I also suggest to not use this code in production environment as this code is likely to disable all security.